# Underlay fixed css image where there is existing html/css code

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I'm looking to underlay a fixed background image to an existing html email. The image would be a full screen cover also. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/vvte6au5/

```
 html { 
      background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: Could you best describe what you would like?

Comment: I would like to add a background image that covers the whole screen, preferably fixed, to go in the html email i attached in the jsfiddle link

Comment: This new image would override the background after some event executed, for example: click?